# Function in ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I've tried to  create a function that takes 2 arguments: a list of strings and the function `String.contains` and return `o` set formed by the strings that returns true in the function string.contains and I got the following error:

```
This expression has type S_String.t = Set.Make(String).t
       but an expression was expected of type S_String.elt list
```

this is what I tried:

```
let f lista = 
  List.fold_left 
    (fun rez x -> 
       if String.contains x 'e' then S_String.add x rez 
       else rez) 
    lista 
    S_String.empty;;
```

Answer (score 1):

`List.fold_left` takes the initial value as the second argument and the list as the third argument. You have them reversed.